Issue with the key aps-environment when publishing from Visual Studio to Apple Store
I'm trying to publish my MAUI application to the Apple Store. I did it a few weeks ago. Because in the app I'm using Push Notification, I added in the Entitlement.plis, the key
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>

With this setting, I have already published the first version of the app in the store. When I try to do it again, Visual Studio raises a generic error

App Store bundle validation failed for archive ... "altool" exited with code 1

Digging a bit, I downloaded on my iMac the Transporter as I read in the Microsoft documentation. With this tool, I can see that there is an error in the key aps-environment

Asset validation failed (90046)
Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value 'development' for key 'aps-environment' in 'Payload/LanguageInUse.app/LanguageInUse' is not supported. (ID: 37d2dd7e-b4e9-4b01-969a-f4605714efe9)


From the Apple documentation the value development is valid. How can I fix this issue?

Development is not a valid value when submitting to the App Store. It is only valid when using a development provisioning profile (ie ad hoc distribution).

According to the answer in aps-environment, you can try replacing development with production and check if the error persists

Have you tried replacing <key>aps-environment</key> <string>development</string> with <key>aps-environment</key> <string>production</string>? Does the problem get solved after the replacement?
